# How to choose gtk version for Eclipse RCP application in linux?

Tags: linux, eclipse, gtk

I have an Eclipse RCP application which I want to run in Linux environment that has multiple gtks installed.

Is there a way to choose the gtk version against which I can run the application?

Linux flavour: openSUSE
Window Manager: iceWM
gtk+ versions installed: 1.2.10 & 2.2.1

Answer (score 1):

It may be possible. You can check the shared libraries loaded by your program with the command *ldd*: for instance,

```
  # ldd /usr/sbin/openvpn
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffffb5fe000)
    liblzo2.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzo2.so.2 (0x00007fc3dc936000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fc3dc719000)
    libpkcs11-helper.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpkcs11-helper.so.1 (0x00007fc3dc4ff000)
    libssl.so.1.0.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0 (0x00007fc3dc2a1000)
    libcrypto.so.1.0.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 (0x00007fc3dbec5000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fc3dbcc0000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fc3db8f8000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fc3dce22000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007fc3db6df000)
```

this shows all libraries invoked by *openvpn*. The libraries whose name ends in *.so.N* where *N* is a single digit (any single digit) are actually links to the real libraries. Take *libz.so.1* as an example:

```
 root@rasal:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu# find / -type f -name 'libz.so.1*' -print
 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.8
 /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.8

 root@rasal:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu# ls /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.*
 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.8

 root@rasal:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu# file /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.*
 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1:     symbolic link to `libz.so.1.2.8'
 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.8: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=0x42bce97e9a0f7a78fcdb3b79d11f67b02abc522c, stripped
```

The *ldd* command shows what the loaded library, *libz.so.1* (btw, this is called the shared library's soname) resolves to, and the follwoing commands find the library, and show that the soname is actually a link to the shared library's *real* name.

You may hope to determine which shared library is loaded by altering this link.

There's  a certain number of caveats to this, the most important of which is that, while you are generally safe in substituting different minor versions of the same major version (for instance, using libz.so.1.2.8 instead of libz.1.1.6) is fine, while substituting versions differing in their *major* number (the first number following *so*) is not possible. According to [the tldp.org page](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html),

> Programs, when they internally list the shared libraries they need, should only list the soname they need.

This implies you will be unable to substitute two versions of the same shared library belonging to different *major* versions.

In any case, I suggest the above link for further clarification.